# Why i get error no such column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Company model and model Invintaton, Companies can invite other companies for messaging and now i need show only companies who confirm the messaging

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_invitations, class_name: 'Invintation', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :invitation_recipients, through: :sent_invitations, source: :recipient 
  has_many :incoming_invitations, class_name: 'Invintation', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
  has_many :invitation_senders, through: :incoming_invitations, source: :sender
end 

class Invintation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
end

class MessagesController < ApplicationController


  def new
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @message = @company.sent_messages.new
    @recipients = Company.joins(:invitation_recipients).where(invitation_recipients: {sender_id: @company.id, confrm: true})
  end
end
```

but i get error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sent_invitations.confrm: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "invintations" ON "invintations"."sender_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "sent_invitations"."confrm" = 't'

And i know this way show only companies who were sending the invitation , and it is necessary , and included an invitation

Comment: Where's your `schema.rb`?  Do you have migrations for those models?

Comment: Does the column exist? Did you run all your migrations? Also, "invintations" is spelled wrong--do yourself a favor and fix it now.

Comment: create_table "invintations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.boolean  "confirm",      default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

Comment: yep all migrations runed

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two typos in your query:

- `sent_invitations.confrm` whereas it should be `sent_invitations.confirm`
- `Invintation` whereas it should be `Invitation`

Review your code and fix the typos, assuming the database schema was not generate with the same spelling errors.

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sent_invintations.confrm: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "invintations" ON "invintations"."sender_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "sent_invintations"."confrm" = 't'

Comment: after destroy model Invintation and create model Invitation rails show error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sent_invitations.confrm: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "invitations" ON "invitations"."sender_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "sent_invitations"."confrm" = 't'

Comment: In my reply I mentioned two typo. Are you sure the column is called  `confrm` and not `confirm`?

Comment: rename confrm to confirm the result is the same

Comment: I think the error is because I have no table sent_invintations